# Grails- spock : turn setup method as normal method

Tags: grails, spock

I am trying to write unit for one of my grails service method, the unit test is like

```
@Shared instance1, instance2, instance3
class testClass extends Specification {
def setup() {
   // initaiting some value here
   instance1 = new Initate(one:"one")
   instance2 = new Initate(one:"one")
   instance3 = new Initate(one:"one")
}

def "testmethodcall"() {
       //testsetup()

       when:
       def result = someMethod(value1) // Here is the error

       then:
          result==value2
       where:
       value      | value1      |   value2
       instance1  | instance2   | instance3

    }
}
```

for some reason we planned to move the codes inside this setup method to another method and plan to call where it is required, like this

```
@Shared instance1, instance2, instance3

class testClass {
def testsetup() {
   // initialize the code what we initialize in setup
   // initaiting some value here
   instance1 = new Initate(one:"one")
   instance2 = new Initate(one:"one")
   instance3 = new Initate(one:"one")
}


def "testmethodcall"() {
       testsetup()

       when:
       def result = someMethod(value1) // Here is the error

       then:
          result==value2

       where:
       value      | value1      |   value2
       instance1  | instance2   | instance3

    }
}
```

As of now it is fine, the method call is working fine, even variable were been initialized, but when I trying to use the data column values it is returning null values, but when I change to `setup()` method I getting the real values. Can someone explain me and How can I able to change the `setUp` method as `normal method`

Comment: I am experiencing an odd behavior of spock here

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note down:-

1. setup() - is used to run with every test case
2. setupSpec() - is used to run once for a test class / unit
3. shared - is visible throughout.And hence must be initialized once, Hence must be within worked upon in setupSpec and not within setup.
4. cleanup() - is run with every test case
5. cleanupSpec - is run in last, after all the test cases has run.
6. Only @Shared and static variables can be accessed from within a where: block.
7. Seperate inputs and outputs expected with double pipes ||

Apart from these point, in your  code testmethodcall method is having syntax errors.

1. no comparison is done
2. expect: is missing
3. why def value is there ,whereas we use data tables variables are declared automatically
   Also, value2 is used no where

Also, you stated that you are able to run test cases successfully with above code when setup() method is there, it's just passing silently without failing as both the value and value1 are null.

Below is a modified version of your code

---

```
def "test methodcall"(){
 setup()
        expect:
        value == someMethod(value1) // Here is the error

        println '----instance1----'+value
        println '----instance2----'+value1
        println '----instance1----'+instance1
        println '----instance2----'+instance2
//        instance1 == instance2
        where:
        value      | value1
        instance1  | instance2
    }
```

---

Now see the println output and you will understand the issue.Hope this would get you answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, anyway that is typo error, you can see my edit question

Comment: Ok!You have used when: and then: rather than expect: now.So is it working now?

Comment: I updated the question, but the answer remains the same